# regarding input name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery mobile and javascript I'm attempting to produce a small quiz which would be functional on a smart phone. It isn't fully finished.

I'm attempting to create a list of radio buttons which one selected the value is carried over and submitted but why is the input name "radio=choice-v-6" when this is one of the options.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var answer1 = 2;
function submit()
{ 
   if ($('input[name=radio-choice-v-6]:checked', '#myForm').val() == answer1)
   {
  alert("Correct");
  window.location = "#question-2"
   } 
   else 
   {
   alert("Incorrect");
   window.location = "#incorrect"
   }
}
</script>
```

then when I use the jQuery mobile pre-set button names I use.

```
<form id="myForm" name="myForm">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" id="radiobuttons" data-mini="true">
        <input name="radio-choice-v-6" id="radio-choice-v-6a" type="radio" onclick="question1()" value="1">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-6a">One</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-v-6" id="radio-choice-v-6b" type="radio" onclick="question1()" value="2">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-6b">Two</label>
        <input name="radio-choice-v-6" id="radio-choice-v-6c" type="radio" onclick="question1()" value="3">
        <label for="radio-choice-v-6c">Three</label>
    </fieldset>
  <td><button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()"></td>
  </form>
```

I assumed I would put the input name as "radiobuttons" or "myForm"

I'm new to JavaScript and would like to know why "radio-choice-v-6" works.

Answer (score 2):

`'input[name=radio-choice-v-6]:checked'` is the selector and targets only the radio button that is checked and has the name of `radio-choice-v-6`. The form in general cannot be deemed as `checked` and neither can the fieldset. So `myForm` and `radiobuttons` will not target the currently checked radio button.